# Problems installing/using expo

Tags: installation, expo

I have installed Expo-Cli using

rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo npm install expo-cli -g

I think it was successful as it ended with

- expo-cli@3.11.5
  updated 1 package in 35.064s

The full response was:

```
rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo npm install expo-cli -g
Password:
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi 
support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
```

npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
    npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/expo -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/expo-cli -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js
    npm WARN @expo/image-utils@0.2.11 requires a peer of sharp-cli@^1.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-x64@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.11.3 (node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/traveling-fastlane-linux):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.11.3: wanted {"os":"win32,linux","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"})

```
+ expo-cli@3.11.5
updated 1 package in 35.064s
```

However, when i try to create a new Expo project, it returns 'command not found: expo'. I tried re-downloading expo-cli many times but it still doesnt work. Please, please help!

```
rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air ~ % cd Desktop
rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air Desktop % cd rn
rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air rn % cd 01
rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air 01 % expo init first
zsh: command not found: expo
rachelchng@Rachels-MacBook-Air 01 %
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me, Expo wasn't included in my `$PATH` variable.

Run `echo $PATH`. If Expo does not show up in there, follow these steps:

Open up `~/.bash_profile` and add

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.npm-global/bin
```

at the end of the file. Save it and finally execute `source ~/.bash_profile`. Then it should work.